# Elapsed time in ruby from an Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, time

I need to get the elapsed time between two arrays (each containing one value) containing time in a Year-month-date H:M:S -ms format in ruby. What is the best way to do this in ruby.

As an example.

[2015-04-10 18:02:05 -0600] minus [2015-04-10 18:02:30 -0600] = result in seconds

Comment: Why are your times in a single-value array? It's like asking how to eat a boxed pizza with a shrinkwrapped fork. Everyone knows how to open the box and unwrap the fork. :p

Comment: Time.parse('2015-04-10 18:02:05 -0600').strftime('%s') gives time in seconds.  Then you can save the fork for Chinese or something.

Comment: @steveklein: No `strftime` needed, `Time#-` returns seconds.

Comment: Cool learned something new... thx @Amadan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'time'
time1 = Time.parse('2015-04-10 18:02:05 -0600')
time2 = Time.parse('2015-04-10 18:02:30 -0600')
time2 - time1
# => 25
```

P.S.

```
boxedPizza = ['2015-04-10 18:02:05 -0600']
pizza = boxedPizza[0]
```